# Why doesn't repaint() in the draw() method work (doesn't call paint())?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a class, which draws black rectangles over the screen directly. How can I fix it to make it work?

```
public class BlackRectangle {
    public Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

    public BlackRectangle() {
        w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        w.setBounds(w.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
        w.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void draw(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        rectangle.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        w.validate();
        w.repaint();

    }

    Window w = new Window(null) {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            ((Graphics2D) g).fill(rectangle);
             g.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paint(g);
        }

    };

    public void clear() {
        rectangle.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlackRectangle rect = new BlackRectangle();
        rect.draw(10, 70, 60, 50);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know/remember Applet syntax very well, but if possible, try to debug your code and step through it.  My guess is that the methods you expect to be called are in fact not being called.

Comment: I just run your code and noticed that paint() is invoked. I get big full screen black window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slowpoke answer.. it worked after changing Window to transparent JFrame and drawing Rectangle to adding Jpanel with black background like this:

```
public class BlackRectangle extends JPanel {


public BlackRectangle() {
    new JPanel();
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void setNew(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}


public void clearPanel() {
    setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

}


   public class FrameTransparent extends JFrame{

public FrameTransparent() {
    new JFrame();
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setSize(screenSize);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}


public class Main {

public static void main (String [] args){
    new Main();
}
public Main(){
    BlackRectangle blackRectangle = new BlackRectangle();
    FrameTransparent frameTransparent = new FrameTransparent();
    frameTransparent.add(blackRectangle);
    blackRectangle.setNew(10, 70, 200, 200);
    frameTransparent.revalidate();
    frameTransparent.repaint();
   }

 }
```